# how to change focus back to textarea in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have `HTML` code to load an audio and write something about it, like this

```
<body>
<audio id="audio-player" controlsList="nodownload" controls src="1294.wav" oncontextmenu="return false;"
    onkeydown="return false;">
    Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>

<form>
    <input type="hidden" name="sysid" id="sysid-field">
    <textarea name="status" id="input_tr" autofocus></textarea>
    <button type="submit" value="ok">OK</button>
</form>
```

I want to when user click on `play` or `pause` or any where on `audio player` the `focus` go back to `textarea`

Used this code but its not working for audio tag

```
const textarea = document.getElementById("input_tr");

document.body.addEventListener("click", function () {
    // Set focus on the textarea element when the user clicks anywhere on the page
    textarea.focus();
});
```

Comment: If you click the document, does the textarea get focus? I ask cause your click event listener is for document.body. Have you tried the audio event handlers for play and pause events?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `focus` event on audio element

```js
const textarea = document.getElementById("input_tr");

document.querySelector('#audio-player').addEventListener("focus", function() {
  textarea.focus();
});
```

```html
<audio id="audio-player" controlsList="nodownload" controls src="https://github.com/prof3ssorSt3v3/media-sample-files/raw/master/jimmy-coffee.wav" oncontextmenu="return false;" onkeydown="return false;">
  Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>

<form>
  <input type="hidden" name="sysid" id="sysid-field">
  <textarea name="status" id="input_tr" autofocus></textarea>
  <button type="submit" value="ok">OK</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<audio id="myAudio" controls>
  <source src="https://www2.cs.uic.edu/~i101/SoundFiles/ImperialMarch60.wav" type="audio/mpeg">
  Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
<textarea id="myTextarea"></textarea>
```

**Javascript**

```
const audioPlayer = document.getElementById('myAudio');
const textarea = document.getElementById('myTextarea');

audioPlayer.addEventListener('play', () => {
  textarea.focus();
});

audioPlayer.addEventListener('pause', () => {
  textarea.focus("false");
});


audioPlayer.addEventListener('click', () => {
  textarea.focus();
});
```